# How to add submit buttons and textbox to the fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

**Basic logic**

Admin could view user submit images using fancybox....When viewing images by image, he could be able to approve images or reject images..when reject images need to add reason for reject.below mock up might explain better

[image: fancybox]

So my questions

1. Is possible to create such a system using fancybox
2. If possible, please could you provide direction

**Edit**

Thank your kumar given me useful link...Now i able to mock up design
     jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/1144/

Now i has more questions

1. How to prevent closing fancybox after approve or reject

   2  How to display success or error messages after action ( using CI)

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18817633/270037). Maybe helpful for you

Comment: Thank you very much..now i able to mock up design....